# Batch Colon not Parsed in Replace

Tags: for-loop, parsing, batch-file, replace

The aim is to follow the example at [ss64:Replace](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html) and hope that the dummy variable in my code *will not change* if the string is not found:

```
Set _cities="Aberdeen, London, Edinburgh"
:: Remove London if found
Set _dummy=%_cities:London=%
IF NOT %_dummy% == %_cities% (ECHO London was found.) ELSE (ECHO London was not found.)
```

Here's my code:

```
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion & pushd "%CD%" & CD /D "%~dp0"

for /D /R %%K in ("*") do (
Set dummy=!%%K:ReplaceThis=!
echo %%K
echo !dummy!
pause
)
endlocal
```

Excepting that dummy turns out to be "Some Directoryname:ReplaceThis=" when "ReplaceThis" does not occur in the string. Is there some magical combination of ", %, !, \ that can keep dummy identical to %%K as per documentation?

Comment: http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1485&start=30

Comment: You can't use the replace syntax with FOR LOOP parameters. First copy it to a variable

Comment: @npocmaka I can't see the relevance of the link here. He searches in all files with a * but he doesn't try to replace a star

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for /D /R %%K in ("*") do (
    Set dummy=%%K
    Set dummy=!dummy:ReplaceThis=!
    echo %%K
    echo !dummy!
    pause
)
endlocal
```

Comment: Great! Tried that originally but with "Set dummy=!!dummy!:ReplaceThis=!". Too smart for my own good :(